# $(window).width(); with use strict mode

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$(window).width();` function is Working Well without use `"use strict"` mode. but, it is not work. after use `"use strict"` mode.

what is wrong here?

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    $('#menu .nav > li').on("mouseover", function() {
        $screensize = $(window).width();
        if ($screensize > 991) {
            $(this).find('> .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
        }
        $(this).bind('mouseleave', function() {
            $screensize = $(window).width();
            if ($screensize > 991) {
                $(this).find('> .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I think the problem ain't `$(window).width()`.  The problem is probably `$screensize` that ain't declared as a var.

Comment: what does "not working well" mean here? are you getting an error? I suspect it's the lack of the `var` keyword before declaring `$screensize`

Comment: I'ts because of the strict mode, you are trying to initialize a var `$screensize` inside of your function (this is assumed as bad practice, but if you are not using strict mode javascript doesn't care about it and defines a new global var) but by using strict mode this will throw an error and therefor your javascript wont work. Source: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using strict mode you need to make sure you declare `$screensize` using the `var` keyword or it will tell you it is an undefined variable. This is likely stopping the execution of your code

[From the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Changes_in_strict_mode)

> First, strict mode makes it impossible to accidentally create global
>   variables. In normal JavaScript mistyping a variable in an assignment
>   creates a new property on the global object and continues to "work"
>   (although future failure is possible: likely, in modern JavaScript).
>   Assignments which would accidentally create global variables instead
>   throw in strict mode

I suggest you make use of your browser's console debugger and get familiar with it. it should be throwing `Uncaught ReferenceError: $screensize is not defined`

Comment: @HarnishDesign this is your problem, same as my comment.